# javascript path is incorrect

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

My script tags look like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content(" ~/Scripts/application/groupplaymanager/commonsignup.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but I am getting 404 errors which show it is trying to load from:

```
http://localhost:8050/lusl-rugby-union/dpmhicvc5u7ncq/~/Scripts/application/groupplaymanager/commonsignup.js
```

The lusl-rugby-union/dpmhicvc5u7ncq/ part shouldn't be there. I had changed the routeconfig to register some other routes so naturally thought this must be the problem, and I did revert all changes I made, but the problem persists.  How to get it looking at the right path please?

Comment: What happens when you do not use Url.Content? Just use `src="~/Scripts/restOfThePath"`

Comment: See if removing the space (or whatever the character is) from before the tilde solves the issue.

Comment: Simply removing whitespace like `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/application/groupplaymanager/commonsignup.js")"` should work. Are you configuring something like `~/lusl-rugby-union/dpmhicvc5u7ncq` as default route for custom errors?

Comment: Ah, somehow in a merge, that whitespace was introduced in all my script tags and I didn't notice. Removing it fixed it, thanks.